# call cd in shell script

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, applescript

I have one shell script opening a perl script. This perl script should be opened in a terminal. I am able to open the terminal but I'm unable to call a cd to reach the perl script's location

```
    $PROJECT_DIR = "$PROJECT_DIR";

    echo "$PROJECT_DIR" > "$PROJECT_DIR/Testing/buildProductPathHello.txt"

osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "pwd"
    do script "cd $PROJECT_DIR" in window 1
    do script "ls" in window 1
    do script "./RunTests.pl" in window 1
end tell'
```

The variable `$PROJECT_DIR` contains the path, I am verifying this by writing the path into a file. Ultimately, it's the command `cd $PROJECT_DIR` is the one that does not work. Does not do cd on the content of the variable.

[image: snapshot of terminal]

[image: snapshot 2]
PS: this is on a mac with a bash shell

Comment: @Charles Duffy .. it does not do a cd on the content of $PROJECT_DIR
Please see the below output...



PHCCWFGML003:~ macadmin$ pwd

/Users/macadmin

PHCCWFGML003:~ macadmin$ cd $PROJECT_DIR

Comment: Let me try to explain again -- it _does_ do the cd, but the process that does the cd immediately exits; your next command, the `ls` (or the `pwd`), is run in a new shell, which is different from the one where the `cd` was done and does not benefit from its effect... but just because the new shell doesn't benefit from the `cd` done by the old one doesn't mean it didn't happen.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Please have a look at the snapshot i just added

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you're wanting to accomplish?

Comment: $PROJECT_DIR = "/Users/macadmin/Documents/"
trying to do a cd on the $PROJECT_DIR variable which has the above content.

Comment: @learningDroid in the example you posted a screenshot from, `$PROJECT_DIR` is clearly unset. (Default behavior of `cd` with an empty argument is to go to the user's home directory; since you were already in the home directory, it just stayed there). Run `echo $PROJECT_DIR` next time you run an example in a terminal to demonstrate the value.

Comment: Ahh! I didn't understand that the outer script was shell -- I thought you had a script in an unknown/undefined language that was _invoking_ shell commands. This makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are specific to each process, too.

The way you're invoking `osascript`, with a single-quoted string, tells the original instance of bash not to substitute for variable names. It actually sends `"cd $PROJECT_DIR"` to `osascript`, which sends `cd $PROJECT_DIR` to Terminal.

But `$PROJECT_DIR` is not set in the receiving bash process – the one running inside your Terminal window. You can verify that by adding a line like `do script "set" in window 1` or `do script "echo $PROJECT_DIR" in window 1`.

If you enclose the part of the script with the variable name in double quotes, the original bash process will substitute the value of $PROJECT_DIR instead:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
    do script "pwd"
    do script "cd '"$PROJECT_DIR"'" in window 1
    do script "ls" in window 1
    do script "./RunTests.pl" in window 1
end tell'
```

(syntax suggested by CharlesDuffy)

Comment: @learningDroid another way to do it would be to keep it an single quotes, but change to doubles only right around the variable dereference... so, use your original code exactly as-is, except change `$PROJECT_DIR` to `'"$PROJECT_DIR"'`; personally, I find that a bit cleaner than adding a bunch of extra escaping.

Answer (score 7):

Each script runs as its own process, does its thing, and exits. The state of the script, including environment variables *and its current directory definition*, is discarded when it exits -- so you can't expect a script that does nothing but "cd" to still have effect later.

If instead you did something like this:

```
do script "cd $PROJECT_DIR; ls; ./runTests.pl"
```

...then that would do all three commands within a single shell, and the results would be what you expect.

Comment: Based on the subsequent screenshots and my own testing, it's apparent that this isn't the exact problem. The effect of `in window 1` is that `osascript` actually sends these four commands, in sequence, to the same shell running inside the same terminal window.

Comment: To handle the possibility of `cd` being unsuccessful, better to write `do script "cd $PROJECT_DIR && { ls; ./runTests.pl; }"`

Comment: Unfortunately, that's no help: `cd` is successful whether or not `$PROJECT_DIR` is set.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for cd in this case; just combine your two calls ie
do script "$PROJECT_DIR/ls" in window 1

Comment: Huh? `ls` is a system command that would be coming off the path, not something in `$PROJECT_DIR`; however, it changes behavior (when called with no arguments) depending on the current directory, so calling `cd` first (or passing an argument) is important.

Comment: I'm guessing this poster meant `do script "$PROJECT_DIR/RunTests.pl"`.